# How to make poster in Lyx?

Tags: lyx

I wanna make a scientific poster. I use lyx as my editor BUT I don't find any instruction how I can make a poster in lyx. I found some latex source codes (.tex) but I don't know how to convert and use them in lyx. I would be happy for your suggestions.

Comment: You may find this helpful: http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=lyx

Comment: This is not the right QA site to ask...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about LyX and should be asked at LaTeX StackExchange.

Answer (score 4):

LyX (2.1.4) has a few templates for posters. For example:

> New from Template...

[image]

I found the `poster-beamerposter.lyx` to be useful since I could easily redefine the dimensions in:

> Document > Settings...

[image]

The `width=121.92` and `height=91.44` are the cm units for 48" and 36" respectively on the `custom` option, as you have to supply cm values in this option.

The template is a pretty confusing in LyX, since it contains various strategies. It requires some experimenting, but the end result is quite nice. I found that using the `i6dv` style was useful, but you have to find/download/debug it yourself.

Proper nesting of frames, columns, blocks, lists, etc. is very important for the result to work properly in this template. Sadly, my copy of LyX doesn't automatically keep the right nesting when you try to add a new `Block` inside a `Column`, or an `Enumerated` inside a `Block`. It's very easy to have things drop down to the outer nesting level and even break the LaTeX.

The other thing that took me some time was to realize that each `Block` needs to have a `Separator` before the next `Block`, else LyX doesn't know how to start a new Block and will fuse things together.

I'd venture to say because of these quirks that posters in LyX are barely less complex than LaTeX itself. Perhaps there's some setting in LyX that I've missed to make it easier.